# Usage of a Diff library

Tags: java, diff

I need a diff library for my project. This is exactly what i need: http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/ 
But when i download the file it doesnt come with a jar file. There are source codes in it and i'm not quite sure how to add this into my application. Anyone knows how to use this in an application? I really appreciate an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing you need to add to your application is the `diff_match_patch.java` file. (Make sure its license is appropriate for your code.)

It doesn't have any dependencies so you can simply compile it with `javac diff_match_path.java`.

The `diff_match_patch_test.java` uses the API (obviously) so you can look in there to see examples of how to use it/what to expect. (The test class depends on jUnit.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to separate it and put under your `lib/` folder, then create a new Eclipse project, copy `diff_match_patch.java` to src folder (with package name of course), then use

```
 File->Export->JAR
```

feature of Eclipse. By this way you can have this file as a JAR archive. This will provide a neat way to keep dependencies organized.